# Cannot get correct max and min values of user inputs

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am writing a method that takes user integer inputs and display the Total, Average, Maximum and Minimum.

I have the total and average working but I am getting 2147483647 for the max and -2147483648 for the minimum.

The loop must only end when the user inputs -1.

My code:

```
public static void processNumbers()
{
    Menu m = new Menu();
    clrscr();

    int count = 0; // Number of times a value has been added
    int num = 0; // The Integer that the user inputs
    int tot = 0; // The total sum of the inputs
    int avg = 0; // The average value of the inputs
    int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // The maximum value of the inputs
    int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // The minimum value of the inputs

    System.out.println ("Please enter a whole number (e.g. 150)");

    while ((num = Genio.getInteger()) != -1)
    {
        count ++;

        tot += num;
        avg = tot / count; //Calculate the average the while loop
        if(tot>max) max = tot;
        if(tot<min) min = tot;

        System.out.println("Total \t Average\t Maximum\t Minimum\n");
        System.out.println(tot + "\t" + avg + "\t\t" + max + "\t" + min + "\n");
    }
    clrscr();
    System.out.println("You entered -1, you will now return to the menu!");
    pressKey();
    m.processUserChoices();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this

```
if(tot>max) max = tot;
if(tot<min) min = tot;
```

Should have been

```
if(num>max) max = num;
if(num<min) min = num;
```

Also, this

```
int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

should be

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

Because no `int` is less then `Integer.MIN_VALUE` or greater then `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. And you want to keep the number as the `max` and `min` not the `total`.

Comment: Thank you! Learned something new, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // The maximum value of the inputs
int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // The minimum value of the inputs
```

Should be swapped because `if(tot>max)` will never be true. Similarly, `if(tot<min)` will also never be true.

Additionally, you need to replace `tot` with `num` if you want to get the min and max of inputs. Putting it all together we get

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
...
if(num>max) max = num;
if(num<min) min = num;
```